# How can I replace asp listbox selection with textbox value?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net listbox that has an option of "Other".  If a user selects "Other" I want to enable a textbox.  When the form is submitted I want the text inside of of the textbox to replace "Other".  So far I have gotten the textbox to enable if the "Other" value is selected but not sure how to replace "Other" with the text from the textbox.  Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#ListBox1").click(function () {
                    var arr = [];
                    $.each($("#ListBox1 option:selected"), function () {
                        arr.push($(this).val());
                    });
                    if ($.inArray("Other", arr) >= 0) {
                        $("#TextBox12").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#TextBox12").prop("disabled", true);
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>

<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
<asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="other"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Blue" Value="blue"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Red" Value="red"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Green" Value="green"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You want the text inside of the listbox to change? That's just weird... (From a UI/ UX perspective) Serverside though, `myVal = myVal != "Other" ? myVal : Model.TextBoxProperty`

Comment: I don't necessarily want the text inside the listbox to change.  What I want is that if a user selects Other, I want the text they type inside of the textbox to be submitted to database and not Other.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with case sensitivity. The listbox item value is `other` but you are trying to find value in the array as `Other`.

```
if ($.inArray("other", arr) >= 0) {
    $("#TextBox12").prop("disabled", false);
}
else {
    $("#TextBox12").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way may be to work through the code behind:

```
protected void TextBox12_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListBox1.SelectedItem != null && ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text == "Other")
    {
        ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text = TextBox12.Text;
    }
}
```